# p5js cannot use height or width variable

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am new to p5.js and I was trying to make a mini game thing to start myself off. I ran into multiple issues that I was able to solve and I have not been able to fix this one.

In p5.js, when you create a canvas you get a `width` and `height` variable, which uses the dimensions of the created canvas and seems to work in other places, like the `draw()` function but not a mini object I am making. My code is below and I thank you if you answer.

```
var Walls = new walls()
function setup(){
  canvas = createCanvas(400,300);
  canvas.parent("lor");

}
function draw(){
  background(22,178,255)
  console.log(Walls.wall1.height);
}
//Walls
function walls(){
  this.wall1 = {}
  this.wall1.width = 30
  this.wall1.height = height/2
}
```

I await your response, as I have spent over an hour trying to figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: How are you calling the `walls()` function? Please post a [mcve] or a CodePen or JSFiddle.

Comment: @Kevin Workman I am calling it with walls() and Walls, Codepen here: [link] (https://codepen.io/cord-codes/pen/bozZBj) and it seems to give something in the console which I cant understand (on the website the link goes to.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the order of your code. The first thing the script runs is `var Walls = new walls();` which is called before setup, where the canvas is created. So what you are doing is calling `height` before the canvas is created. This can simple be solved by declaring the global variable but giving it a value inside setup.

```
//Declaring the empty variable
var walls;

function setup() {
  //creating the canvas
  canvas = createCanvas(400, 300);

  //calling Walls()
  walls = new Walls();
}

function draw() {
  background(22, 178, 255);
  console.log("Height: " + walls.wall1.height);
}

function Walls() {
  this.wall1 = {};
  this.wall1.width = 30;
  this.wall1.height = height / 2;
}
```

Height: 150

Comment: This was a huge help, thanks a million! Would have probably never worked it out without this